# Envio de recado com foto e exibição

Tags: php, jquery, upload, file-upload

Bom dia galera, estou com uma dúvida, fiz um sistema de recados e gostaria de adicionar na postagem uma imagem e exibir ela como as mensagens são exibidas.

Meu código é:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Mural de Homenagens - Anjo da Guarda</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
      <video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
  <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
<source src="./videobg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

    <div class="webcodo-top" >
        <a href="http://webcodo.com/comments-system-using-php-ajax">
            <div class="wcd wcd-tuto"> Afagu</div>
        </a>
        <a href="http://webcodo.com">
            <div class="wcd wcd-logo">Afagu</div>
        </a>
        <div class="wcd"></div>
    </div>

    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


<?php
// Connect to the database
include('config.php');
$id_post = "1"; //the post or the page id
?>
<div class="cmt-container" >
  <div class="new-com-bt">
      <span>Escreva uma homenagem...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="new-com-cnt">
      <input type="text" id="name-com" name="name-com" value="" placeholder="Seu nome" />
      <input type="text" id="mail-com" name="mail-com" value="" placeholder="Seu e-mail" />
      <textarea class="the-new-com"></textarea>
      <div class="bt-add-com">Compartilhar</div>
      <div class="bt-cancel-com">Cancelar</div>
  </div>
  <br/>
    <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id_post = '$id_post'") or die(mysql_error());;
    while($affcom = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $name = $affcom['name'];
        $email = $affcom['email'];
        $comment = $affcom['comment'];
        $date = $affcom['date'];

        // Get gravatar Image
        // https://fr.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/
        $default = "mm";
        $size = 35;
        $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5(strtolower(trim($email)))."?d=".$default."&s=".$size;

    ?>
    <div class="cmt-cnt">
        <img src="<?php echo $grav_url; ?>" />
        <div class="thecom">
            <h5><?php echo $name; ?></h5><span data-utime="1371248446" class="com-dt"><?php echo $date; ?></span>
            <br/>
            <p>
                <?php echo $comment; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end "cmt-cnt" -->
    <?php } ?>



    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- end of comments container "cmt-container" -->


<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
        //alert(event.timeStamp);
        $('.new-com-bt').click(function(event){
            $(this).hide();
            $('.new-com-cnt').show();
            $('#name-com').focus();
        });

        /* when start writing the comment activate the "add" button */
        $('.the-new-com').bind('input propertychange', function() {
           $(".bt-add-com").css({opacity:0.6});
           var checklength = $(this).val().length;
           if(checklength){ $(".bt-add-com").css({opacity:1}); }
        });

        /* on clic  on the cancel button */
        $('.bt-cancel-com').click(function(){
            $('.the-new-com').val('');
            $('.new-com-cnt').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $('.new-com-bt').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });

        // on post comment click
        $('.bt-add-com').click(function(){
            var theCom = $('.the-new-com');
            var theName = $('#name-com');
            var theMail = $('#mail-com');

            if( !theCom.val()){
                alert('Você precisa escrever um comentário!');
            }else{
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/add-comment.php",
                    data: 'act=add-com&id_post='+<?php echo $id_post; ?>+'&name='+theName.val()+'&email='+theMail.val()+'&comment='+theCom.val(),
                    success: function(html){
                        theCom.val('');
                        theMail.val('');
                        theName.val('');
                        $('.new-com-cnt').hide('fast', function(){
                            $('.new-com-bt').show('fast');
                            $('.new-com-bt').before(html);
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comentarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `comentario` text NOT NULL,
  `id_post` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Gostaria de enviar a imagem para meu ftp e armazena-la em uma pasta e exibir também.

Comment: Sua pergunta não fez muito sentido. Onde estará essa imagem nos comentários? Como exatamente você pretende enviá-la ao servidor? E como pretende exibí-la? Cada imagem estará associada a um comentário? Se sim, existe no banco de dados esta relação? O que esses seu código faz? O que ele deveria fazer?

Comment: Isso é o que eu quero fazer parceiro, eu sou iniciante, gostaria de adicionar o um input pra envio de foto